# Erro 229 no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Eu criei um usuario no SQL Server 2014 e em seguida fiz o login com o usuario criado. Quando fui atualizar a pasta **Table** ele aparece essa mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o usuario que criei não esta tendo permissão de visualizar as tabelas.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Revisões de outros usuários existem justamente para melhorar o texto originalmente postado. Mesmo que palavras ou frases sejam substituídas, não há necessidade de editar novamente para desfazer as edições e pior, reverter inclusive erros orto-gramaticais ora corrigidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho experiência com SQL Server, mas talvez informações trazidas [do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002773/permissions-issue-in-ssms-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-exte) possam lhe ajudar.

Segundo o tópico, nessa ordem:

- Você não deve deletar nenhum certificados ## do master
- Você não deve marcar, ou deve deletar, a função (*role*) de permissões **db_denydatareader** e, caso haja problemas de escrita, a *role* **db_denydatawriter**
- Você pode precisar adicionar o nome usuário à *role* **public** -OU- dar permissões de visualização estendida *sys.extended-properties* para ele em *System Views* do banco de dados que esteja tentando acessar.

Comment: você escreveu de uma maneira tão técnica que não entendi o que você quis dizer.

Comment: @wladyband traduzindo: você criou um usuário mas não definiu nenhum privilégio para ele.

Comment: É, basicamente.

Comment: Qual dos três cenários foi o correto?